# Moduler scss styles not reflecting after publishing vite-react app as a package

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sass, vite

I've deployed a private github repo (vite+react) as npm package in github package repo.

Styling from my modular `scss` files is not reflecting. Styling from global `scss` files are working.

Screenshots from dev tools:
[image]
[image]

The modular className `_container_13ixh_1` has no styling whereas the className `primary-h4-semi-bold` is working fine - those are coming from global `scss` files.

My vite config:

```
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import path from 'path';
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import dts from 'vite-plugin-dts';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
    build: {
        lib: {
            entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'index.ts'),
            name: 'leafs-intake-web-temp',
            fileName: (format) => `index.${format}.js`,
        },
        rollupOptions: {
            external: ['react', 'react-dom'],
            output: {
                globals: {
                    react: 'React',
                    'react-dom': 'ReactDOM',
                },
            },
        },
        sourcemap: true,
        emptyOutDir: true,
    },

    plugins: [react(), dts()],
    server: { port: 3000 },
});
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank!

Comment: its because the component css is scoped to component only. if the container / heading is from a lib or other components, you will have to use `deep` concept.

Comment: It's a functional component called <Dashboard /> which imports styles like `import styles from "./index.module.scss` and uses it like `<div className={styles.container}></div`.

Comment: I tried copying the css file generated in dist from the package to the codebase where I'm using it, and styling is working. But, if I try to import it directly from the package, it says - `Missing "./dist/style.css" specifier in "@Lamndj/leafs-intake-web-temp" package`

Comment: can you please add the `style` file of the functional comp and how you used it? Please add the relevant code.

Comment: Solved it. I made my css file exportable from the package and imported it in the new repo where I was using it. That solved it, styles are being applied now.